# I keep get the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Im not entirely sure what is going wrong, my what I'm looking at everything should be running fine but I'm obviously missing something. Hoping someone here can help. When I run the program and attempt to submit any of the items in the combo box i receive the error at the "txtYear.Text = dt.Rows(1).Item(1)" line.

```
 Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Dim strSelect As String = ""
    Dim strModel As String = ""
    Dim cmdSelect As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim drSourceTable As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

    If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then
        MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database Connection Error." & vbNewLine &
                        "The Application Will Now Close.",
                         Me.Text + "Error",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        Me.Close()
    End If

    strSelect = "Select strMake, strYear, strMileage FROM TAutos WHERE intAutoID = " & cboModel.SelectedValue

    cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)
    drSourceTable = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader

    dt.Load(drSourceTable)

    txtMake.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
    txtYear.Text = dt.Rows(1).Item(1)
    txtMileage.Text = dt.Rows(2).Item(2)

    CloseDatabaseConnection()


End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `dt.Rows(1).Item(1)` to `dt.Rows(0).Item(1)` Do the same for txtMieage.Text code as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been staring at this thing for hours trying to figure out that simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the member @Harsh for providing this answer. Simple enough, all I had to do was change dt.Rows(1).Item(1) to dt.Rows(0).Item(1) and do the same with txtMileage.Text